# Visio: Get the value from my connectors

Tags: vb.net, visio

I'm currently trying to build a macro for visio
The goal of this macro is to calculate the value from the former shapes and multiply them by the value on my connector

So imagine I've:

[10]======>[Result]( the text value on my connector ===> is 0.5),
So, Result would show 5, so I'm able to get the text from the shapes and I convert it into integer but I find nothing for the Connector
So someone knows how could I do that?

Comment: There isn't anything differnent (in terms of the text) between a 1D shape and 2D one.  Do you have some code to show what you're trying at the moment?

Comment: Thanks
It was only that, I tought that visio make a difference between connectors and shape, but it doesn't